# Spring data specification with subquery and multiple in clause

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I would like to create a specification with subquery and multiple in clause, how can I do it with JPA criteria?

basically, I want to convert below native SQL to spring data specification?

```
SELECT * FROM table
where (x_id, version) IN (select x_id , max(version) from table group by x_id)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Native query is not an option?

Comment: @pringi nope it is not an option since I have many other filters.